# Hide Shadow on androidX Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx, appcompatactivity

I want to hide the shadow below the `ActionBar` to make the `ActionBar` look flat. There should be no line, shadow, border between `ActionBar` and the layout.

**Constraints**

- Unfortunately I have a constraint that there must be an `ActionBar` involved. I cannot simply remove the `ActionBar` and set whitespace on the top of the screen.
- Another constraint is that I want to toggle the visibility of the shadow at runtime from code.

What worked for me on the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` does not work for me on the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

I tried several things like

- setting the `supportActionBar`'s elevation to 0 has no effect at all
- setting the `elevation` of the `AppBarLayout` to 0 has no effect at all
- setting the `elevation` of the `Toolbar` to 0 has no effect at all
- setting the `alpha` to 0 makes the `ActionBar` invisible but I need a visible and functioning UpButton

  ```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
  ```

So far nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me is to set the elevation of the `AppBarLayout` in code. Unfortunately in a `Fragment` you need to know in which `Activity` you are and need access to its `AppBarLayout` and that is something that makes the code ugly. In the future there should be a function for that in the `SupportActionbar` like show/hideShadow() or so.

Long story short. What I did to hide/show the shadow of the `ActionBar`

**In your Activity**

```
appBarLayout.elevation = 0f
```

**In your Fragment**

```
if (requireActivity is MyActivity) {
    (activity as MyActivity).appBarLayout.elevation = 0f
}
```

Keep in mind that if you change the ActionBar from your Fragment, that all other Fragments hosted by the same Activity will see the changes too.

Another problem is testing as in Espresso your Fragment will be launched in an EmptyActivity that has no `AppBarLayout`. But at least with the above code your App does not crash.

Comment: Hey @Emanuel do you know how solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72609914/11560810)